# setting emacs inferior process prompt location

Tags: python, emacs, elisp

I love emacs and I am trying to get the best setup for python development. I am currently using elpy mode along with the python3.4 interpreter, and it works great. One thing that bugs me lately is how my prompt defaults to the middle of the buffer. There is a lot of wasted space this because of this.

Does anyone know how to tell emacs to keep my prompt at the bottom, like a normal shell prompt? I imagine it's something like:

```
(setq prompt-on-bottom-of-buffer t)
```

Here are my settings for comint-output-filter-functions:

```
(setq comint-output-filter-functions 'comint-truncate-buffer
                                comint-buffer-maximum-size 1000
                                comint-scroll-show-maximum-output t
                                comint-input-ring-size 500
                                comint-scroll-to-bottom-on-input t)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty much ;)

```
(setq comint-scroll-to-bottom-on-input t)
```

Comment: I do have this feature enabled already as a comint-output-filter-function, but I added it as a standalone as well in my .emacs. Did not seem to make a difference. Maybe I haven't implemented it properly.

Comment: Not sure how that makes sense as an output filter function, OTOH, adding ```comint-postoutput-scroll-to-bottom``` as an output filter function may solve your problem.

Comment: Your second suggestion works! But I had to replace my `comint-truncate-buffer` with `comint-postoutput-scroll-to-bottom` in my code in the question. Do you know how I can pass multiple functions into `comint-output-filter-functions`?

Comment: You would probably have to redefine ```comint-send-output``` and/or ```comint-output-filter``` to change their call of ```run-hook-with-args```. Either of which I would strongly advise against..

Answer (score 1):

Question is quite old, but there is another variable to this puzzle which is `comint-move-point-for-output`

And also, `python-inferior-mode` resets `comint-output-filter-functions` locally, so it's advised in documentation to rewrite/override it using `inferior-python-mode-hook`. Since `python-inferior-mode` already sets `comint-postoutput-scroll-to-bottom`, we only need to do one thing:

```
(add-hook 'inferior-python-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (setq comint-move-point-for-output t)))
```